# RabbitMQ and Nodejs on Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am looking for a sample applications with a pub/sub where one nodejs program accepts input of queue/message name and the other nodejs program displays the messages sent to the same queue. I am trying to use RabbitMQ as the message broker. I need to deploy this application in Cloud Foundry.

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a project from a friend and colleague of mine.

https://github.com/ecs-jbariel/rabbitmq-tester-node

It is a "NodeJS Producer/Consumer for RabbitMQ".

Try it out.